# Mathematic questions in python

Tags: python, math

Looking on for some guidance on how to write a python code
that executes the following:

The program will ask for math problems to solve.
The program will asks for the number of problems.
And asks for how many attempts for each problem.

For example:

Enter amount of programs: 4
Enter amount of attempts: 5

what is: 4x3 =?
Your answer: 16

and so goes on to another attempt if wrong if correct moves onto another problem, just like before and exits when attempts or problems are finished.

I have this code but I want to it only do multiplication ONLY and would like to know how to integrate how to put additional code to limit how many time one can solve the question and how many questions it asks

```
import random




def display_separator():
    print("-" * 24)


def get_user_input():
    user_input = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    while user_input > 5 or user_input <= 0:
        print("Invalid menu option.")
        user_input = int(input("Please try again: "))
    else:
        return user_input


def get_user_solution(problem):
    print("Enter your answer")
    print(problem, end="")
    result = int(input(" = "))
    return result


def check_solution(user_solution, solution, count):
    if user_solution == solution:
        count = count + 1
        print("Correct.")
        return count
    else:
        print("Incorrect.")
        return count


def menu_option(index, count):
    number_one = random.randrange(1, 21)
    number_two = random.randrange(1, 21)
    problem = str(number_one) + " + " + str(number_two)
    solution = number_one + number_two
    user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
    count = check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)
        


def display_result(total, correct):
    if total > 0:
        result = correct / total
        percentage = round((result * 100), 2)
    if total == 0:
        percentage = 0
    print("You answered", total, "questions with", correct, "correct.")
    print("Your score is ", percentage, "%. Thank you.", sep = "")


def main():
    display_separator()

    option = get_user_input()
    total = 0
    correct = 0
    while option != 5:
        total = total + 1
        correct = menu_option(option, correct)
        option = get_user_input()

    print("Exit the quiz.")
    display_separator()
    display_result(total, correct)

main()
```

Comment: Your `menu_option` function is doing addition, not multiplication.  You're not asking for the number of problems or the number of attempts here, but `menu_option` is where you would add a loop that continues until either they get the right answer, or they exceed the number of attempts.

Comment: any way you can help me with code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as making sure you're only allowing multiplication problems, the following function should work.

```
def valid_equation(user_input):
    valid = True
    for char in user_input:
        if not(char.isnumeric() or char == "*"):
            valid = False
    return valid
```

Then after each user_input you can run this function and it will return True if the only things in the users string are numbers and the * sign and False otherwise. Then you just need to check the return value with a if statement that tells the user that their input is invalid if it returns False. You can add more "or" operations to the if statement if you want to allow other things. Like if you want to allow spaces (or char == " ").

As far as limiting the number of times a user can try to answer, and limiting the number of questions asked, you just need to store the values the user enters when you ask them these numbers. From there you can do nested while loops for the main game.

```
i = 0
user_failed = False
while ((i < number_of_questions) and (user_failed == False)):
    j = 0
    while ((j < number_of_attempts) and (user_correct == False)):
        #Insert question asking code here
        #In this case if the user is correct it would make user_correct = True.
        j += 1
    if j == number_of_attempts:
        user_failed = True
    i += 1
```

So in this situation, the outer while loop will iterate until all of the questions have been asked, or the user has failed the game. The inner loop will iterate until the user has used up all of their attempts for the question, or the user has passed the question. If the loop exits because the user used up all of their attempts, the for loop will trigger making the user lose and causing the outer loop to stop executing. If it does not it will add one to i, saying that another question has been asked, and continue.

These are just some ideas on how to solve the kinds of problems you're asking about. I'll leave the decision on how exactly to implement something like this into your code, or if you decide to change parts of your code to better facilitate systems like this up to you. Hope this helps and have a great one!